Android Studio failed to render code：Render problem
I'm a beginner in Android, I'm currently trying to develop in the Kotlin, and I'm using Jetpack Compose.
It's a very simple page, but Android Studio doesn't render renderings properly
This is the error page
Here's the code
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun MainUi() {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val backgroundColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.yellow)
    val subBackgroundColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.milk_white)
    val topBarTitle = ContextCompat.getString(context, R.string.home_title)
    val topAppBarColors = TopAppBarColors(
        containerColor = Color(backgroundColor),
        titleContentColor = Color.White,
        scrolledContainerColor = Color(backgroundColor),
        navigationIconContentColor = Color(backgroundColor),
        actionIconContentColor = Color(backgroundColor)
    )
    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color(backgroundColor))
    ) {
        TopAppBar(
            title = { Text(text = topBarTitle) },
            colors = topAppBarColors
        )
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(Color(subBackgroundColor))
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "This is the content of the page",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(16.dp)
                    .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
            )
        }
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun MainPreview() {
    WPJ_KotlinTheme {
        MainUi()
    }
}

If anyone knows the reason or solution, please tell me, thank you very much ! ! !
I tried to clean up and rebuild the project
And I updated Android Studio
Android Studio version

My experience has been that for some reason it can't find the resources in the preview, does it render correctly if you only use colors like Color.yellow for example instead of from the R.color.yellow etc.
Does it render correctly when running the app?

I think  WPJ_KotlinTheme is your custom theme. As a suggestion please remove such codes when asking questions, it will make importing the code for others easy.

To know exact problem you can click on the "Render issues" text

In this case the problem was a internal problem of compose. Problem is happening because you are not using the things as you are supposed to in Compose.

You should use "colorResource" & "stringResource" methods for reading colors and strings and other similar methods to get values from R class.
Here is a working code
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun MainUi() {
    val backgroundColor = colorResource(id = R.color.yellow)
    val subBackgroundColor = colorResource(id =  R.color.milk_white)
    val topBarTitle = stringResource(id = R.string.home_title)
    val topAppBarColors = TopAppBarColors(
        containerColor = backgroundColor,
        titleContentColor = Color.White,
        scrolledContainerColor = backgroundColor,
        navigationIconContentColor = backgroundColor,
        actionIconContentColor = backgroundColor
    )
    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(backgroundColor)
    ) {
        TopAppBar(
            title = { Text(text = topBarTitle) },
            colors = topAppBarColors
        )
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(subBackgroundColor)
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "This is the content of the page",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(16.dp)
                    .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
            )
        }
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun MainPreview() {
        MainUi()
}


Thank you for your responses
I tried the following two changes
// val topBarTitle = ContextCompat.getString(context, R.string.home_title)
val topBarTitle = context.getString(R.string.home_title)

// val topAppBarColors = TopAppBarColors()
val topAppBarColors = TopAppBarDefaults.topAppBarColors()

The problem was solved successfully
